# Named Routes with anchor tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a default route in my `startup.cs` Configure method:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

I navigate to a page with the following url:

```
http://localhost:59977/Home/Index/somedata
```

On that above page, I created an anchor tag helper like below:

```
<a asp-route="default">default route</a>
```

When I go to view the page on a web browser and look at the anchor element it shows

```
<a href="/Home/Index/somedata">default route</a>
```

My question is this. Why has it added the id part (`somedata`) to the link?  I called the route by name and would assume it would use the default options set out in `MapRoute`, which means id is optional and I did not specify one.

Comment: It's part of your URL !

Comment: But this is a new request to the server. if I added asp-route-id="moredata" to the above tag helper it would add the moredata to the end of the url (and not somedata, which is what I would expect)

Comment: but you navigate to `Home/Index/somedata` not to `Home/Index/default`, the default route is `Home/Index/{id?}`, `somedata` is your id. In your code you wrote `asp-route="default"` not `asp-route-id="default"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `asp-route` instead of `asp-controller` and `asp-action`, all of the values in `RouteData` are re-used for your `<a>` tag.  This means that `controller` is set to "Home", `action` is set to "Index", and `id` is set to "somedata" because that was the `id` field.  The default values specified in the route are only used when values do not already exist for those fields.